# Set time for API call - How can I set up a specific time for my website to make an API call?

Tags: html, api

I currently have connected Metals API (https://metals-api.com/) to my online calculator (https://miningcatalyst.com/)

At this moment, eveytime when I refresh the website an API call is made. How can I set up the API in a way that only one API call per day is made - lets say at 12am - and all the website users will see the corresponding data for the 24 next hours untill the next API call is made?

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $.get("https://www.metals-api.com/api/latest?access_key=KEY&base=USD&symbols=XAU,XAG,XCU,ZNC,NI,LEAD,TIN,XPT,LITHIUM", function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    var rates = data.rates;
                    console.log(rates);
                    $("#D36").val(Math.round((1/rates.XPT)*100)/100);
                    $("#D8").val(Math.round((1/rates.XAU)*100)/100);
                    $("#D12").val(Math.round((1/rates.XAG)*100)/100);
                    $("#D16").val(Math.round(((1/rates.XCU)/0.0625)*100)/100);
                    $("#D20").val(Math.round(((1/rates.ZNC)/0.0625)*100)/100);
                    $("#D24").val(Math.round(((1/rates.NI)/0.0625)*100)/100);
                    $("#D28").val(Math.round(((1/rates.LEAD)/0.0625)*100)/100);
                    $("#D32").val(Math.round(((1/rates.TIN)/0.0625)*100)/100);
                        
                });
```

FYI: D8 - D36 correspond with the different commodities from the 'commodity price deck'

I am not that well versed in coding that I can produce the outcome I have described above.

Comment: So first, you should not include your access key in your post, especially if it's one you paid for.  If you did pay for it, you might want to get a fresh, new key, unless you want random people from the internet consuming your allocation of API calls.

Comment: Second, I think there may be a fundamental misunderstanding of how webpages and API calls work.  When you open this webpage, it's going to make the API call.  You could cache the instance of this call, and its results, in `localstorage` or something, and then you can update your code to ask `localstorage` "have I called this API already today?  If so, use the cached values".  But your other users don't have access to your localstorage, so they will also hit the API once per day.

Comment: If you want to restrict all users of your site to just a single combined API call per day between them, you need some shared resource that can track this - essentially you will be setting up an API of your own, which all visitors to your site will call.  The first visitor of the day will call your API, which in turn will trigger a call to the Metals API, and then your API will cache the response.  The second visitor to your site will call your API, but since the API has already been hit today, it will just return the cached values instead of calling the metals API directly.

Comment: Getting this setup will be a bit of work, and honestly I am not an expert in this area.  You could look at something like an AWS Lambda Function that calls the Metals API and then caches the result into an S3 bucket or something.  Or I'm sure other folks with more backend experience will have better recommendations than this.